MultiProject coverage check issue with class scan inclusion
i have some issues with jacoco-maven-plugin.
My project structure is similar to:
Root
|- ModuleA
|- ModuleB
|- ModuleC

In my ModuleA i have some java classes plus a dummy unit test.
In my ModuleB i have some java classed plus some springboottest.
Module C is used for other things.
Now, i'd like on ModuleC to aggregate reports of the two other modules, plus doing a code coverage check.
ModuleC has A and B as dependencies.
ModuleC configuration is :
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.9</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- Report execution -->
        <execution>
            <id>report-aggregate</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>merge-exec</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>merge</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-merged.exec</destFile>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/../moduleA/target</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>jacoco.exec</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/../moduleB/target</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>jacoco.exec</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>check</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-merged.exec</dataFile>
            <rules>
                <rule>
                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                    <limits>
                        <limit>
                            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                            <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                        </limit>
                    </limits>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>

So far so good.
The report is generated.
The aggregated exec does generate itself.
What is failing is the code-coverage check.
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.9:report-aggregate (report-aggregate) @ moduleC 
---
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\workspace\prj\moduleA\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\workspace\prj\moduleB\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'moduleA' with 97 classes
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'moduleB' with 86 classes

As we can see the aggregated report is ok
Next is the merge:
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.9:merge (merge-exec) @ moduleC ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\workspace\prj\moduleC\..\moduleA\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\workspace\prj\moduleC\..\moduleB\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] Writing merged execution data to C:\workspace\prj\moduleC\target\jacoco-merged.exec

The file is being created and is not empty.
The issue is here:
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.9:check (check) @ moduleC ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\workspace\prj\moduleC\target\jacoco-merged.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'moduleC' with 0 classes
[INFO] All coverage checks have been met.

So i am not able to let moduleC see the classes on moduleA and moduleB, i tried with includes of check but nothing so far. What i am doing wrong?
